# L system equations

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

This is my first program on my second try to learn haskell :)

```
import Data.Maybe (mapMaybe)
import Control.Exception (try, IOException)
import System.Environment (getArgs)

type Rule = (Char, String)
type Axiom = String
type LSystem = (Axiom, [Rule])

getRule :: Char -> [Rule] -> String
getRule ch [] = [ch]
getRule ch ((rulekey, rulevalue):rest)
        | ch == rulekey = rulevalue
        | otherwise = getRule ch rest

lSystemIterate :: Int -> LSystem -> String
lSystemIterate 0 (axiom, _) = axiom
lSystemIterate n (axiom, rules) =
        lSystemIterate (n-1)
        (concatMap (\ch -> getRule ch rules) axiom, rules)

splitRule :: String -> Maybe (Char, String)
splitRule (x:' ':rest) = Just (x,rest)
splitRule _ = Nothing

readLSystem :: String -> IO (Maybe LSystem)
readLSystem filename = do
        strorexc <- try $ readFile filename :: IO (Either IOException String)
        case strorexc of
                Left _ -> return Nothing
                Right [] -> return Nothing
                Right str -> return (Just (ax, mapMaybe splitRule rules))
                             where (ax:rules) = lines str

iterateIOMaybe :: Int -> IO (Maybe LSystem) -> IO (Maybe String)
iterateIOMaybe n = fmap $ fmap (lSystemIterate n)

main = do
        args <- getArgs
        case args of
                (n:filename:[]) -> do
                        maybelsystem <- readLSystem filename
                        case maybelsystem of
                                Just lsystem -> putStrLn $ lSystemIterate (read n) lsystem
                                Nothing -> putStrLn "File doesn't exist, or it is empty"
                _ -> putStrLn "Usage: progname iterations filename"
```

Program invocation is something like this: `runhaskell lsystem.hs 3 dragon.ls` assuming that it is saved as lsystem.hs.

It takes two arguments, first argument is number of iterations, second argument is a filename to read L-System from.

File structure is simple, first line is axiom, each line of the form 'x ys' treated as transformation rule. So, something like this:

```
FX

X X+YF+
Y -FX-Y
```

As output, program should return something like;

```
FX+YF++-FX-YF++-FX+YF+--FX-YF+
```

So, how does it look?

Answer (score 2):

This is good! You have restricted imports, type aliases, type signatures on all top-level definitions (except `main`, which you *should* add but is at least obvious), total functions... All I've got are details.

`splitRule` should use the `Rule` type alias in its return. I.e., `splitRule :: String -> Maybe Rule`. I would probably also name that function “`readRule`,” `split` refers to an implementation detail; you are providing the function with what you know (or hope) is a single serialized rule to be parsed, not (say) dividing a rule off by splitting it into two.

I might also reconsider your error handling with `readRule`, right now your program silently discards rules it can't parse. That's certainly a valid choice but you might find that it actually makes sense to halt program execution on badly defined input, like so—

```
readRule :: String -> Rule
readRule (x:' ':rest) = (x, rest)
readRule bad          = error $ "readRule: Can't parse " ++ show bad
```

Just something to think about. Note also how I aligned both cases of the function on `=` so their right hand sides start in the same column. This can be tedious but aligning things like multiline functions or lists can really help readers of your code as they scan through, the extra whitespace and visual similarity helps stop your Haskell code from looking like word soup.

You could do with another few type aliases as well to clear up the purposes of `Char`s and `String`s in your program. At the very least I'd give—

```
type Predecessor = Char
type Successor   = String
type Rule        = (Predecessor, Successor)
```

I think the type of `getRule` is more obvious then.

```
getRule :: Predecessor -> [Rule] -> Successor
```

It also shows that `getRule` might not be the correct name, because the function doesn't actually return a `Rule` but instead the application of the set of system rules (or the identity production if the `Predecessor` is a terminal). I think `apply` makes sense here.

The remaining set of changes I have are all function implementation related. You can leverage `Prelude` functions to achieve a lot in Haskell, doing so often makes your code more readable as common patterns get expressed by familiar names.

For instance, `apply` looks a lot like finding an element in an association list, which in the `Prelude` is provided by `lookup :: (Eq a) => a -> [(a, b)] -> Maybe b`. Digging a little further into `base` we can also deal with that `Maybe` using `Data.Maybe.fromMaybe :: a -> Maybe a -> a`.

```
apply :: Predecessor -> [Rule] -> Successor
apply p rules = fromMaybe (terminal p) $ lookup p rules

terminal :: Predecessor -> Successor
terminal p = [p]
```

The next thing I'd recognize is that lazy evaluation helps simplify dealing with potentially infinite sequences of values. Instead of generating a finite number of states in `lsystemIterate`, generate every state lazily and return the iteration requested.

```
states :: LSystem -> [String]
states (axiom, rules) = iterate (concatMap (`apply` rules)) axiom

after :: LSystem -> Int -> String
after l n = states l !! n
```

(You also seem to have some dead code, `iterateIOMaybe`.)